# found maas user directory in tmp?

Tags: maas, tmp

I am somewhat new to servers, and even more fresh when it comes to Ubuntu.  I am looking on my Ubuntu folder and found a directory owned by a user maas...

```
drwx------  2 maas  maas  4096 Dec 22 00:26 pymp-mqVtZh
```

Is this a normal folder to find in /tmp/ or should I be concerned of some virus

Answer (score 1):

Even if you wonder what is happening the permissions on the file clearly state your "maas" user has read, write, execute permissions and nobody else; not even a group "maas" is part of.

For something to be problematic I would assume that the "others" part of the permissions (the last 3 dashes) would be "rwx".

Just looking at it from that perspective this seems perfectly normal to me.

---

If you look [around the web](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2098854&p=12425214#post12425214) the "maas-import-pxe-files" script seems to use /tmp/ to store temporary files. It seems more likely this file is from running that script.

Besides that "maas" uses "touch /tmp/block-poweroff" to not ask for a reboot.

So seems legit to me.